# Java does not run prepare statements with parameter

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, ora-00942

I am using PreparedStatement to query my table. Unfortunately, I have not been able to do so.

My code is as simple as this:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
"Select favoritefood from favoritefoods where catname = ?");

preparedStatement.setString(1, "Cappuccino");                
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The error thrown is `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character`. As if it never run through the parameter given.

Thanks for your time. I've spend a day to debug this yet still unsuccessful.

As mention by Piyush, if I omit the semicolon at the end of statement, a new error is thrown. `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. But I can assure you this table is indeed exist.

**UPDATE**

shoot. i edited the wrong sql. now it is successful. thx for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get this error if you try binding values from the shown sql and excute it from the SQL prompt or any SQL editor?
Make sure your query is not having semicolon (";") at the end of it or anywhere in the query.

Comment: i can run the statement directly on TOAD, and got result. It just seems that, java doesnt replace the parameter. it execute the code with the question mark intact.

Comment: @Piyush i've updated my code. after omitting semicolon at the end, new error is thrown.

Comment: Can you post the relevant JDBC code here? You may be connecting to the wrong database from JDBC - please check that. Also, try schemaName.tableName like Select <schemaName>.favoritefood from favoritefoods

Comment: yes, wrong schema. my first mistakes was the semicolon. 2nd is wrong datasource. thx @Piyush

Comment: Good Job! Can you mark it answered please in case you think it is answered?

Comment: For marking answers as useful, you need to click on up arrow on the relevant answers that you found useful. There would be a right sign arrow to mark the answer as an accepted answer. You may have to wait till you have some reputation to do so though.

Answer (score 0):

try giving it this way..

```
String query="Select favoritefood from favoritefoods where catname = ?";
preStat = conn.preparedStatement(query);  // conn is the connection object
preStat.setString(1,"Cappuccino");
ResultSet resultSet=preStat.executeQuery();
```

Comment: You just keep the sql in separate variable right? i've done this and the same error happen.