# Java does not run prepared statement with parameter and not throwing any errors

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jdbc

I'm trying to execute a query as simple as the below in a 'VIEW' of my MSSQL database. Not successful after trying for 2 days. So I'm turning to SO.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
"SELECT * FROM Vw_Transactions WHERE Cust_No=? ");

preparedStatement.setString(1, "1234");                
ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

The problem is I don't get any response back after the query.Not even an error. Not even after waiting for a long time e.g. 3mins. Once or twice I got some result after waiting for upto 5 minutes. But that's useless. I'm curious to know why before I do something stupid like semi-sanitize and string concantenate arguments to the query, as the last resort.

### **Interesting Observations:**

- The same query works from java when I hard code the customer id into
  the string and skip prepared statement. It brings the result very fast so now I'm sure it's not data load that is causing slowness.
- The same query works if I run
  it in the Visual Studio console when I use the sample customer id
  directly
- The same query *format* works if I choose a different VIEW
  from the database

The only last log I can see is :

```
> SQLServerPreparedStatement:3: calling sp_prepexec: PreparedHandle:0, SQL:SELECT * FROM Vw_Transactions WHERE Cust_No=@P0
```

Note: I've already referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177476/java-does-not-run-prepare-statements-with-parameter) quesiton and mine is not a duplicate scenario. I already made sure I havent dont those mistakes.

Comment: What sql datatype field `Cust_No` is?

Comment: Depending on datatype for `Cust_No` you might be forcing SQL Server to do a integer-to-string conversion for all your customer numbers (assuming Cust_No is numeric). This would be done for all rows and would ignore all indexes set on Cust_No inside the view. So... did you actually do `WHERE Cust_No = '1234'` when comparing query speed?

Comment: @Jan In Visual Studio I can see the `Data Type: char ` . Yes I did ` WHERE Cust_No= '1234' ` to hardcode the parameter in the String in my java class. The result was very fast.

Comment: Same might happen if you send nvarchar parameter for String and then conversion to char (single byte charset) happens. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx and try setting  `;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` in your connection URL to your database

Comment: Yay! It works, I would have never known about it without someone like you saying it to me. SO is awesome! I cant thank you enough. Can you post it as the answer and any more links that will help me learn all about how you knew about this conversion happening behind the screens. I'll accept it asap. Thnx thnx thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your Datatype for `Cust_No`, sqljdbc driver might send the String in unexpected format.

This would then force a data conversion to happen in SQL Server, rendering all indexes useless on that table / view.

As your `Cust_No` is of type `char` in SQL Server, this would be a charset conversion in this case.

As http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988(v=sql.110).aspx points out, String parameters are send as Unicode ( = `nvarchar`) by default, causing your query to perform `char` to `nvarchar` conversions for all `Cust_No`.

Try adding `;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` into your connection string to disable this feature.